# Xamarin Forms crossPlatform: force to repaint

Tags: xamarin.forms, cross-platform, repaint

I know i know: probably it is one of the most asked questions. Before you send me some LMGTFY links, let me tell that I've been some hours with this question, and I've made some tries with Invalidate, PostInvalidate, RunOnUIThread, etc; with no success. I do not discard that the solution can be one of the previously mentioned,  and I have not been using it properly. I am actually learning Xamarin, doing my first crossplatform app, so my knowledge of the framework is very poor.

So now let's go to my concrete problem, and let's see if someone can help me. I want a intro page for my app, with a progress bar and a text below saying what is doing the app (when starting the app, it calls a WS to download changes, and has to load info from text files and put it into some static data structures to use for all pages). What i want to do in the loading page is the following sequence:
    1. Change text to tell what is the app doing.
    2. Call WS or load a file.
    3. Update progress bar.
    4. Go to next update or to the welcome page if all is loaded.

What i get for my actual code is that the page is load when all the stuff is done, so I see the progress bar completed and the last text change. But is a static page, i don't see the progress bar growing neither the text changing.

This is my code:

```
 public partial class LoadingPage : ContentPage
 { 
        InitializeComponent();
        this.lpb.Text = "Connecting to web server to check updates";
        App.localInfo.updateInfo(); //Connect web server to check updates
        this.pb.Progress = 0.2;
        this.lpb.Text = "Loading info from local files";
        App.localInfo.cargarInfo(); //Load local files to memory for quick access
        this.pb.Progress = 0.7;
        this.lpb.Text = "Doing other stuff"; //This is only for proves

        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            await Task.Delay(2000);
        });

        this.pb.Progress = 1;
        this.lpb.Text = "Load completed. The app will start now";
 }
```

And this is my ContentPage:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="Prueba1.Views.LoadingPage">
     <ContentPage.Content>
         <StackLayout>
             <ProgressBar x:Name="pb" Progress="0.0" ProgressColor="Red"/>
             <Label x:Name="lpb" Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!"/>
         </StackLayout>
     </ContentPage.Content>
 </ContentPage>
```

This is only the alpha version. I would like to concrete a little more, because I have to load around 10 different text files, and I would like to update progress bar and label inside the App.localInfo methods. But first I have to learn how to do this simple stuff, and then trying something more complicated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setting the progress property like you are, try using the progress bar's [ProgressTo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.progressbar.progressto?view=xamarin-forms#Xamarin_Forms_ProgressBar_ProgressTo_System_Double_System_UInt32_Xamarin_Forms_Easing_) method inside an async method. Something like:

```
public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        FireProgressBar();
    }

    async void FireProgressBar()
    {
        lpb.Text = "Connecting to web server to check updates";

        // Task.Delay to simulate network call.
        await Task.Delay(2000);

        await pb.ProgressTo(.2, 250, Easing.Linear);

        lpb.Text = "Loading info from local files";

        // Task.Delay to simulate network call.
        await Task.Delay(2000);

        await pb.ProgressTo(.7, 250, Easing.Linear);

        lpb.Text = "Doing other stuff";

        // Task.Delay to simulate network call.
        await Task.Delay(2000);

        await pb.ProgressTo(1.0, 250, Easing.Linear);

        lpb.Text = "Load completed. The app will start now";
    }
```

This has the added benefit of actually seeing the progress bar moving, not just jerking from one value to the next.

Comment: Awesome! It works perfectly, thanks a lot! I've been testing changing your Taks.Delay for my updateInfo/cargarInfo and it turns back to the original behaviour. I fixed it by adding an "await Task.Delay(1);" before any void I want to invoke. 

So, for learning a bit of Xamarin, I assume that if i want a void to refresh the app several times before ending I have to create an async void and put a line "await Task.Delay(2000);" will force it to repaint. Is it right??

Comment: No. The `Task.Delay(2000)` was just to simulate the time it took to make the network call. I've added that as a comment in my answer. Ideally, your method setup would be `async Task FireProgressBar()` and you would use it like `await FireProgressBar();`. You can't await in the constructor though, which is why it just returned void. Take a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/platform/async#using-async--await) for some more information on using async/await.